# How do I access ALL the nginx logs in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have the following in my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:  
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    container_name: nginx
    environment:
      NGINX_DOMAIN: mydomain.com
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ${DIR}/nginx:/var/log/nginx
      - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
    restart: on-failure:5
    network_mode: host
```

This will forward access.log and error.log files to /my/dir/nginx. How do I also forward access1.log, error1.log and all the other rotated logs? Alternatively, I don't need to actually forward the logs to the directory as I can just access them directly I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand the question...

You are mounting a volume on the /var/log/nginx folder, if you do so, you will have all the logs that are inside the folder, if a rotation exists they will simply appear as in nginx log folder.

Comment: that's exactly what I thought. I have 2 files: access.log and error.log and they get updated and appear normal. The rotated logs just don't appear.

Comment: I just thought of it, but is there logs inside of the log files? By default the nginx docker image push the log in stderr and stdout, so there shouldn't be values in the log files.

Comment: Looks like it is just appending to one big file.